# Footnotes as bibliography in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

Is it possible to create a bibliography from footnotes in Word Office 365? If so, how?

Comment: Does it need to be a proper Word bibliography or can it be a manually created one?

Comment: @Crimsonfox It doesn't need to be a proper one. As long as it shows all of the sources I used as footnotes...

Comment: Welcome to [Super User](https://superuser.com/ "https://superuser.com/"). Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask "https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask") then edit your question.   Pay particular attention to the section titled [Search, and research](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask:~:text=Search%2C%20and%20research)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? We expect people to have researched and tried things and to share this in the question so we know what not to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this cannot be done, as a footnote is not a citation
and contains no data fields as it's just text, and also Word's
Citation Manager can't work with footnotes.

There is a procedure for it, but it requires some work.
Do the following on a copy of your document.

- Convert all the footnotes to endnotes at the end of the document:

  - Position to the References tab
  - In the Footnotes group click the little square at the bottom
  - Click Convert... and Convert all footnotes to endnotes
- In the endnotes list, click just before the first endnote
- Scroll to the end of the endnotes
- Hold the Shift key and click at the end of the last endnote
  to select all the endnotes
- Press Ctrl+C to copy to the Clipboard
- Open a new blank document and paste (Ctrl+V) the endnotes.
  You now have a document that has just the endnotes
- Sort the paragraphs alphabetically
- Edit the endnotes, deleting the text and references that
  you don't need
- Structure and format as desired.

Sources :

- [Creating a Bibliography from Footnotes](https://word.tips.net/T000514_Creating_a_Bibliography_from_Footnotes.html)
- [How to convert several hundred footnotes in a word document into a bibliography/reference list](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-convert-several-hundred-footnotes-in-a-word/e53dc17c-4df7-493f-bebc-f11ee769cbf4)